# LayoutInflator issue

Tags: android, layout

I've a list view with custom list adapter (`list_item.xml`). I have multiple layout folder to support multiple screen size. I found out when I inflate using `LayoutInflater`, it's always taking the view from main "layout" folder.

I've a phone with screen size "427x320". This is my code:

```
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public ListAdapter(Context context, MenuPage menuPage, Activity activity) {
        // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

}
```

How do I get the layout inflater to pick the `list_item.xml` from "layout-427x320" folder and not the "layout" folder?

Answer (score 0):

First, Android does not support 427x320 as a screen size. Second, `layout-MMMxNNN` has been deprecated.

Visit Table 2 [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/resources-i18n.html#AlternateResources) and find out the right values (`layout-small`, maybe?) that will work for your project.